# Creating repeatable columns for a Sharepoint 2010 List

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to create a list that allows me to store multiple instances of a single column.

Say I have a column names "steps" which is a single line of text, and I want the user to be able to add as many as possible.

Can I do this currently in Sharepoint Lists?

Bonus points for allowing me to do it in a LoopUp column, for more complex types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a "Custom Field Type" to do this. Then you can delimit your different lines somehow (the internal columns link Multi-lookup, multi-choice etc use ;# as a delimiter but you can use whatever)

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms446361.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb684919(v=office.12).aspx
- http://sharepointmagazine.net/articles/customizing-the-user-experience-of-sharepoint-custom-fields-deep-dive-part-5-of-6